# Mapster. Классы помеченные атрибутом не компилируются

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mapper

Есть пара объектов

```
public record ProductDTO(string Title, string Description);
public record Product(string Id, string Name, string Description);
```

Хочу чтобы **Mapser** показывал ошибки маппинга при компиляции.

Если я добавлю конфигурацию через **GlobalSettings.ForType**, то получу то, чего и ожидаю:

Из-за не соответствия названия полей **Title/Name** и включенном **RequireDestinationMemberSource** при компиляции вызовется **Exception**

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.RequireDestinationMemberSource = true;
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.ForType<Bar, Foo>(); // Добавим конфигурацию
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Compile(); // Exception: corresponding source member mapped or ignored:Title
```

[Как написано в документации](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Config-location#attributes), добавить конфигурацию можно и с помощью атрибутов **[AdaptTo]**, **[AdaptFrom]**

```
[AdaptFrom(typeof(Product))]
public record ProductDTO(string Title, string Description);
public record Product(string Id, string Name, string Description);
```

Но в этом случае при компиляции ошибки не происходит, а происходит она уже **при вызове метода Adapt**

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.RequireDestinationMemberSource = true;
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Compile(); // успешно

var product = new Product("1", "Name", "Description");
var productDTO = product.Adapt<ProductDTO>(); //Exception:corresponding source member mapped or ignored:Title
```

Добавление сканирования:

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Scan(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Проблемы не решает.

Как скомпилировать конфигурации Mapster, написанные через атрибуты?